# scritp selenium python no funciona en vm gcp

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Mi script de selenium no funciona en esta pagina cuando va a ejecutar driver.execute_script('AutenticaCUnica();') no funciona.Alguien sabe cual
puede ser el error

Este problema solo lo tengo en mi server de ubuntu de gcp

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='drivers/chromedriver')

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://oficinajudicialvirtual.pjud.cl/home/index.php')

horaInicio= datetime.datetime.now()
print(driver.current_url)

time.sleep(4)
driver.execute_script("AutenticaCUnica();")
```

me sale el siguiente error:

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: AutenticaCUnica is not defined
(Session info: headless chrome=84.0.4147.89)

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente la funcion esta presente, pero puede que el tiempo de espera no sea suficiente. En este caso puedes aumentar el tiempo de espera o implementar la espera por la aparicion de algun elemento (por ejemplo, del final de la pagina):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
...
myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'cuform')))
// ejecutar codigo JS
```

Ademas puedes verificar que la respuesta de la pagina sea la misma que recibes desde tu computadora. A veces las paginas que reciben solicitudes desde ubicaciones remotas (otro pais o region) pueden llevar a una pagina distinta a la que tu ves.

```
html = driver.page_source
```

Guarda este valor o imprimelo en la pantalla para ver si la salida es la misma que tu ves.